# How to install a Linux Kernel that is older than 2.6.13?

Tags: kernel

I am currently trying to install version 2.6.10 or 2.6.13 of the Linux kernel, however I do not know how to accomplish this.

I have tried going on to download the image and headers file for version 2.6.10 on the old releases Ubuntu website, but other answers has said to find a generic all.deb file which doesn’t exist for older versions.

Comment: Way back then, there wasn't a separate all.deb file.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? To use the latest kernel, you have to use latest Ubuntu release, which will upgrade your kernel automatically when you run apt upgrade.

Comment: Any software that *requires* this kernel or lower likely has not been updated in a decade. You might consider running a VM with an archived release.  Please don't give it access to the internet.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for doing this?  Will probably be easier to use a VM or USB with ubuntu version that old that contains that kernel.

Comment: You need to install virtual box, download the Ubuntu version that has this kernel and install that into virtual box. But since all those are end of life you get no support ;-)

Comment: Hello there, apologies every for the late reply. I managed to get this working by installing this version on Virtualbox. My reason is that I wanted to experiment with congestion control algorithms and I found only this version has access to other algorithms that are discontinued

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  No current version of Ubuntu or the supporting packages support kernel versions that old, and any such version of Ubuntu that supported this kernel version is beyond End of Life.